# Python Linear regression line error. how do i keep a straight line?

Tags: python

[image]

For the above image, the regression lines are scribbled around and i don't know why? any help would be great.

Comment: Please add code not images. This way we can reproduce the example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that you are passing in `data['size']`, which is not sorted and goes between a value on the left and then to the right. The `plt.plot` always connects points, which is why you get squiggly line back and forth.

Now if this is a simple `y = a + bx` then I would recommend that you pass in an `x` input (e.g., `x_range = [min(data['size']), max(data['size']`) that is the minimum and maximum of `data['size']`. Then define `yhat_no`, `yhat_yes`, and `yhat` accordingly with `x_range`.

However, I see that you have a dependence `data['year']`, so the expectation of a single linear line will not happen.